# What options does the spell Revenant Armor allow for?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, animated-objects

I've been looking at the spell [Revenant Armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/revenant-armor) and its unclear what you would use it for.  I know that it brings the armor to life after the person wearing it drops unconscious, but is the only thing you can do with it really tell the armor to move or escape a grapple?

Those two effects are useful, don't get me wrong, but for avg spell level 4, it doesn't seem like it does enough.  This might be my unfamiliarity with the rules around animated objects, so if I am misunderstanding something there, I would greatly appreciate any clarification.

As a bonus, what would the strength score of medium armor be, as the spell doesn't say and following the links in the chain ([animated objects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/animated-object), [building constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs)) doesn't tell me as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spell doesn't merely animate your armour.

> ...the armor is immediately brought to life as a Medium-sized animated object.

It animates it as an [animated object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/animated-object), which is a kind of creature. As a creature, it can fight - attack enemies, trip, disarm, flank, you name it. Your allies can ask it to move, but not control its actions otherwise.

[Medium animated objects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/animated-object/animated-object-medium) have 14 Strength.

Comment: Thanks!  I've dealt with animated objects so little I didn't know what they did (or apparently even how to navigate the page).

Comment: > it can attempt to break free with a Strength score equal to your caster level (from the spell description). So it is unclear does the spell override the standard medium animated object strength in every situation or only in the graple.